# gmaps.js - Drawing a Polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gmaps.js

I am using gmaps.js and I can draw Polygons using this code

```
var paths = [];
function drawPoly(p1, p2) {
  paths.push([p1, p2]);
  console.log(paths);

  oldPolygon = null;

  map.drawPolygon({
      paths: paths,
      strokeColor: '#432070',
      strokeOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 3,
      fillColor: '#432070',
      fillOpacity: 0.6
    });
}
```

But my problem is that they are overlapping each other resulting to this,[image]

My question is how do I remove the overlapping Polygons(Old Polygons) so that the remaining Polygon will be the last generated one. I hope I explained it well. Thanks.

Comment: For each square/rectangular polygon, you are actually adding 4 polygons (a point, a line, a triangle and the polygon you want).  That is pretty inefficient, why not just pass the complete path into the drawPolygon function?  You can certainly "fix" your problem by deleting or hiding the 1,2 and 3 point versions, but are all your polygons going to have 4 points?

Comment: No, the polygons will not have a fixed number of points. The point, line and triangle are generated because I am calling that function drawPoly(p1, p2) in the 'click' property of GMaps. May I ask for ideas on how to delete the point, line and triangle?

Comment: Why can't you pass the complete path to your `drawPolygon` function?

Comment: Because I don't know when will the user stop adding points.

Comment: Will there only ever be one polygon?  Perhaps you should provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Thanks anyways sir. I just solved my issue. I just removed the point, line and triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix to my issue was to use the `map.removePolygon` method:

```
var paths = [];
var oldPolygon;
function drawPoly(p1, p2) {
    paths.push([p1, p2]);
    console.log(paths);

    polygons = map.drawPolygon({
       paths: paths,
       strokeColor: '#432070',
       strokeOpacity: 1,
       strokeWeight: 3,
       fillColor: '#432070',
       fillOpacity: 0.6
    });

    // remove old one if exists.
    if(oldPolygon != null){
        map.removePolygon(oldPolygon);
    }

    // ... and save a reference to the new polygon for next time around.
    oldPolygon = polygons;
}
```

Comment: What was the fix?

Comment: It is the if-condition. The old polygons just needs to be removed so that they will not overlap each other. Thanks bob for editing.

Answer (score 0):

If you realy want to use polylines or polygons you could use:

```
.setMap(Null)
```

You can find more about that here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-remove

But i think u might want to use editable polygons: https://jsfiddle.net/3L140cg3/16/